# How to get many more diamonds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Diamonds are so rare that you can hardly build diamond tools or armour. Even with a Fortune 3 pickaxe, the supply is small.How can you have many more diamonds with which you can easily go through Nether and The End,but also beat enemies in the Overworld?

Comment: I have absolutely no objection to your posting self-answered questions; but you should really check that the question hasn't already been asked first. If it has, just post a new answer to that question instead of asking a new one. Based on your answer though, it's also possible that you've simply not worded the question appropriately. You *could* edit to be more along the lines of "how to I make more diamond ore blocks spawn in new worlds?", **then** it would be a different question from the one I linked.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is valid but if you want to be more legit about it, all I can say is mine, explore, and put in the hours.

Comment: I play most games on large biomes,that can't be customized,and I often mine through walls,but caves are even better.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the "Customize" option for the Customized world type. Go on the second page and find "diamond ore". Do the following:

```
 1.Set the spawn tries to max
 2.Set the spawn count to max
 3.Set minimum height to min
 4.Set maximum height to max
```

Now you have a world with so many diamonds that you can build a palace out of them.Don't forget to also increase the iron ore spawn rates to have tools with which you can mine the first diamonds.Without gravel, you won't be able to lit your Nether Portal,so increase a bit the rate of spawn for gravel too.Works better if you start in Extreme Hills. Enjoy!

Comment: Hey, if you want to play Q&A like that, you could at least mark your question  as answered...

Comment: I can do that in 2 days.

Comment: Soooo... You are there just to increase your reputation ?

Comment: @ Ealhad I asked that because I DON'T WANT TO CHEAT and give myself reputation.

Comment: Cheat ? What the hell ? Are there really people cheating to get a score on a help website ?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't know.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question. It's really no different from answering someone else's question. If it's a helpful question/answer, it will get upvoted. If it's a stupid simple question/answer, just there to try to get rep, it will get downvoted. Just like any other question/answer.

Comment: The Q&A is a good way to inform others,anyway. They decide then if give you votes ,which can affect(even negatively) the reputation. See my last post before this for an example. @Ealhad

Comment: @John Sure, it's just that this question doesn't seem that useful to me, since it's a basic option of the game. But hey, I can be mistaken.

Comment: I can be mistaken too,because I posted this,but you never now...Also,when I said this to other person,he was impressed(or he seemed like).Anyway,let's break this discussion.Anyway,let those that don't know yet see this. @Ealhad

Comment: You can't earn reputation on your own answer of your question because people think it's a good was of getting lots of reputation if they allowed earning reputation.